# How to change the login parameters on the default Laravel 6 login form

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-ui

I am new to Laravel. Please I am trying to change the authentication mode of the default laravel login. This is what I am trying to achieve :

1. Get users to login using only a 4 digit PIN.
2. Redirect the user to the default home page after login

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screen Clip]

Comment: have you write any controller or edit LoginController,php . please provided the code.

Answer (score 1):

You may find login (authentication) logic on `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`, as you see on this file, it uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

> 1. Get users to login using only a 4 digit PIN.

You may override existing `credentials` of `AuthenticatesUsers` method on `LoginController` or try [adding custom user provider](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers).

> 2. Redirect the user to the default home page after login

Change the `$redirectTo` property on `LoginController` to your desired route:

```php
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```